# scrub document of BBcode

Tags: php, bbcode, ipb

Say I have a document like:

```
 [b]blah[/b]
 [img]Thisismyimage.png[/img]
```

How can I make it so that I completely remove all of the BBcode tags. And also remove all the text from between the [img] tags.

If it helps at all I am using an IPB board. If any knows of a way to easily to parse the BBcode that would be great, however, I am perfectly happy with just removing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing BBcode is pretty much a solved task: http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser - And that would also be the more advisable path for removing (for simplicity just apply `strip_tags()` afterwards).

But for removing a limited set of syntax constructs, you could use a very simple regex:

```
 $text = preg_replace('#\[img].*?\[/img]|\[/?\w+.*?]#', '', $text);
```

Comment: The BBcode parsing isn't that easy given that I am developing on an IPB board. The preg_replace is perfect though. Is there any way I can use preg replace to just remove all bbcode?

Comment: This example should remove all singular bbcode tags, plus that one special [img] case. It will not remove any bbcode tags with attributes `[xy a=b]` for example. You'll have to try if that's usable in your case.

Comment: I'll be honest I really cannot wrap my head around regular expressions I would GREATLY appreciate it if you could provide and example of how to also remove bb code tags that have attributes.

Comment: I did add another `.*?` catch-all for optional bbcode attributes. That's not a very professional approach (could be more exact), but I don't know your actual used bbcode syntax.. Could be problematic if you have spurious square brackets in the text. Else worth a try.