# Prevent spammer to sneak in URL & link in mail

Tags: php, preg-replace, htmlpurifier

I have a spammer that use my PHP e-mail contact form and write this in the mail message:

```
[url=http://qjtouvifclfk.com/]qjtouvifclfk[/url]
[link=http://gqmrjhtujkoe.com/]gqmrjhtujkoe[/link]
http://tkihpjlwszyw.com/
```

I want to search for anything that ha `[url=` and `[/url]` and `[link=` and `[/link]` and `http://` and `.com` in the message and remove it.

Comment: what? i really dont know what you are asking...

Comment: Rather than trying to be clever and strip it out, I'd just detect and reject.

Comment: Check out this page for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260194/scrub-document-of-bbcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/\[url=(.*)\](.*?)\[\/url]\/i", "", $text);
preg_replace("/\[link=(.*)\](.*?)\[\/link]\/i", "", $text);
preg_replace("/http:\/\/\/i", "", $text);
preg_replace("/\.com/i", "", $text); //this is very agresive line!
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens all the time.  Automated bots will POST on your forms, searching for something they can use as a spam relay.

There are many methods for working around it.  The most common is CAPTCHA, but your users will hate you.

See this post:  [Alternative to Captcha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514130/alternative-to-captcha)

Comment: CAPTCHA is being unuseful as time flows. These bots get through CAPTCHA in seconds

Comment: @genesis, did you read my post?  There is a reason I linked to "Alternatives to CAPTCHA"

Comment: okay sorry. But if he would have known site, question like "What's color of sky(pe)" would not  help

Comment: I've always wondered whether the CAPTCHAs in several file-download websites are just to prevent abuse or whether their users are unknowingly solving CAPTCHAs for spammers...

Comment: @thkala: It's to force users to buy premium and to prevent free users from using download managers

Comment: @genesis: so the fact that in many cases each CAPTCHA differs stylistically from the previous one, and that they occasionally seem way too similar to the ones used by major freemail providers is a mere coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the same thing about 2 years ago. Add a honey pot to your contact form. This is an extra input which is hidden with CSS then in your PHP check that it has an empty value before running your mail script. Honey pots stop spam bots from filling out your forms, I've used this on 50+ sites so far with no problems. Let me know if you want more info on how to.